# There is an issue that I cannot find as I have just started coding with the cs50 class and something isn't right here

Tags: c, cs50

Here is my code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void);
{
    string name = get_string("What's your name? \n")
}
{
    printf("hello, %s\n", name);
}
```

The compiler output these errors:

```
me/ $ make hello
hello.c:4:1: error: expected identifier or '('
{
^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
2 errors generated.
make: *** [‹builtin›: hello Error 1
me/ $ make hello
hello.c:4:1: error: expected identifier or '('
{
^
1 error generated.
make: *** [‹builtin>: hello Error 1 
me/ $ ^C
me/ $ make hello
hello.c:4:1: error: expected identifier or '('
{
^
1 error generated.
make: *** [‹builtin>: hello Error 1 me/ $
```

I have tried changing my `;` and `{}` and `()` but nothing has helped, I consulted the internet but couldn't find a fix anywhere, I would appreciate any troubleshooting or potential fixes, I really want to learn coding so I hope I am not just dumb and blind.

Edit: Thank you for the comments, I didn't realize I could have both in the same set of braces I appreciate the help.

Comment: You are missing a `;` at the end of line 5 and line 7+ are outside of `main` because of the odd braces.

Comment: You should not have a `;` at the end of `main(void)`, but you *should* have one after `get_string`. And you only need two braces, not four.

Comment: You need to pay more attention to punctuation.

Comment: @BoP: The braces `{` and `}` after `main` specify the start and the end of the function, so all code belonging to `main` must be inside that first set of braces.

Comment: There is a difference between a *typo*, a stray character typed by mistake, and a misunderstanding of the C syntax which this is an example of. A simple answer does help the OP, a complete beginner who missed some basic explanations that may actually be absent from the CS50 tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

- The definition of function `main` should not have a `;` after the argument list but a function body as a single block of statements surrounded by `{` and `}`.
- individual C statements and definitions end with a `;`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    string name = get_string("What's your name?\n");

    printf("hello, %s\n", name);
}
```